# Why is my program able to only successfully process large amounts of data when iterating over strings instead of lists?

Tags: python

I was sifting through problems on Hackerrank — and I stumbled across a confusing roadblock. The following are the rules of a game that must be programmed ("Minion Game"):
Both players are given the same string.
Both players have to make substrings using the letters of the string.
Stuart has to make words starting with consonants.
Kevin has to make words starting with vowels.
The game ends when both players have made all possible substrings.

For example, in the string BOB, OB would be considered a valid word/substring that starts with a vowel, hence a point would be awarded to Kevin.

While attempting this program, I created the following program:

```
def minion_game(string):

    v = ['A','E','I','O','U']
    c = [
            'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M' ,'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
            'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y' 'Z'
        ]

    L = list(string)

    s = 0
    k = 0

    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i] in v:
            k += len(L) - i
        elif L[i] in c:
            s += len(L) - i

    if s > k:
        print(f"Stuart {s}")
    elif k > s:
        print(f"Kevin {k}")
    elif k == s:
        print("Draw")
```

The program is valid for most of the test cases, however, in test cases where the inputted string is large, the program fails. For example, for one of the test cases, the expected output was Stuart 406312, and for some reason, the program I created failed.

I then created the following program, and it worked for all test cases:

```
def minion_game(string):
    vowels = 'AEIOU'
    length = len(string)
    k, s = 0, 0

    for i in range(length):
        if string[i] in vowels:
            k += (length - i)
        else:
            s += (length - i)

    if k > s:
        print("Kevin", k)
    elif k < s:
        print("Stuart", s)
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

My question is — why did my first program fail some of the test cases whilst my second program passed all of them? Is it because I used strings instead of lists, and why does that make a difference (efficiency aside)?

Thanks for taking the time in advance.

Comment: Someone else posted a question about the Minion Game last week. His error was that he didn't convert the input to the same case as his list of vowels. It looks like you have the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748977/python-the-same-programs-has-2-different-outputs-on-2-different-compilers

Comment: @Barmar Changed the first program to L = list(string.upper()). HackerRank was still throwing back an error. I decided to remove the c list altogether and just award Stuart the points if the indexed string wasn't a vowel (using else). The program then passed all test cases. Any clue as to why this made a difference (I checked the c var, and it included all the consonants)?

Answer (score 0):

[String search](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/#a_4) in Python uses `fastsearch` it is a mix between [Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) plus couple of neat tricks. Lookup costs `O(1)`.

In case of lists you just scan it for an item, the cost is `O(n)` for every lookup.